# Using Google Custom Search as a image scraper?

Tags: filter, web-scraping, image-uploading, google-custom-search

I want to scrape images that coincide with specific text. I want it to filter these, check for new images periodically, and upload the results to a program.

Do i have to set up a website to do this? Are there better tools? Which method is the most simple? I'm a bit overwhelmed by the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use google search for *scrape images that coincide with specific text*. 
Remember that google is sensitive to the web scraping, particulary to the frequent requesting of its server for search pages. Read [this post](https://webscraping.pro/search-queries-in-a-search-engine-for-scraping/) to get into it (search result pages are somehow similar to querying [business directories](https://webscraping.pro/business-directories-scrape)).

> Do i have to set up a website to do this?

Absiolutely not (for google regular search). If you want to use Google Custom Search, you do need to set up a website.

> Are there better tools?

Best method, I think, is a custom scraper (python, php). But again, scrape with a tempered speed, lest google ban you or put out [CAPTCHA](https://webscraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge/).

> Which method is the most simple?

If you are short of programming skills, turn to [the web scraping software](https://webscraping.pro/software-for-web-scraping/).

Comment: It looks like google custom search has a reasonably low barrier of entry, and if i'm right about the control panel i don't need a website. It's a small pool of results, so i'm alright with staggering the scrape.